# Is there a way to get a color of a new line to not affect the color of a line that is already there?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```js
var notRunning = true;

function getRandomColor() {
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]; 

}
return color;

}

function drawLines() {

var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingPlace");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var verPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 499) + 1);
var theColor = getRandomColor();

context.linewidth = 10;
context.moveTo(10, verPos);
context.strokeStyle = theColor;

context.lineTo(500,verPos);
context.lineCap = "butt";
context.stroke();

}

var animation

document.getElementById("startParty").onclick = function() {
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
drawLines();
}

}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="startParty" value="Start Party!">
<canvas id="drawingPlace" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Evertime a new line is generated it alters the other lines color.

I have tried moving the function that generate a new color into the function that generates the new line hoping it would be called when a new line is drawn and it still does the same.

Comment: You are working with only a single [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#drawing_paths). You never use the [methods to close it or begin a new one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#paths).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! now I understand about more about the animation aspects of JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You should put your line drawing between `context.beginPath()` and `context.closePath()`.

Change this

```js
  context.linewidth = 10;
  context.moveTo(10, verPos);
  context.strokeStyle = theColor;
```

to this

```js
  context.beginPath();
  context.linewidth = 10;
  context.moveTo(10, verPos);
  context.strokeStyle = theColor;
  context.closePath();
```

and it will work as needed.